# Android Studio names parameters incorrectly for SharedPrefences.getString()

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

Android Newbee here. Got a issue on

Sharedpreferences().getString("KEY", defValue).

```
private void saveSharedPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("C2000",0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString(getString(R.string.pdk),persistentDataEditText.getText().toString());
}

private void restoreSharedPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("C2000",0);
    persistentState = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.pdk),"");
}
```

Screenshot can be viewed below:

[image: My Code]
[image]
I am wondering why the code suggestion isn't key , defvalue. Instead it shows up String string.

Here is another screenshot of my Friend's android code. 
The suggested parameter type of his last line of code is **key, defValue.**

[image]

Comment: are you talking about the `getString` method? Also this question is specific to Android studio, not Android JDK.

Comment: I think I am asking about sharedPreference API. The getString is used to fetch the value of my SharedPreferences object named sharePref. However, the parameter is supposed to show up like my second image. ---> the KEY and defValue.

Comment: SharedPreference is not a method it is a class. The first image you posted is too small, we can't see. Ok so you are talking about the `SharedPreference.getString` method

Comment: Can you try `new SharedPreferences().getString("", "");`, you will see that it name the parameters `key` and `defValue `. See my answer for explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see on your image the `String string` you are talking about, however, here is an explanation of how android studio works regarding naming parameters.

**key** and **defValue** are not suggested parameter **types**, they are the names of the parameters of the method definition. It is just a visual help (added by Android Studio) so you can see at a glance what the parameters are.

You can try it for yourself, declare the following method:

```
private void myMethod(boolean param1, boolean param2) {}
```

Then do

```
myMethod(true, true);
```

Android studio will show

```
myMethod(param1: true, param2: true);
```

In the same way, the `SharedPreferences.getString` method is declared as

```
String getString (String key, String defValue)
```

[see API here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

If you try this:

```
new SharedPreferences().getString("", "");
```

Android studio will show

```
new SharedPreferences().getString(key: "", defValue: "");
```

Comment: Sorry about the image. Can you try to right click on the image and click on open image in a new tab.

Comment: It is not clickable, someone edited the link to insert the image in the post, but may have reduced the image, could you edit your question and post the link to the image again?

Comment: Somehow, problem solved. Thank you for being the first to respond on my first post. Thank you!

Comment: @VincentHuang If my answer helped you then upvote and accept it, cheers!